# Spring Web Application: Shutdown if initialization fails

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a Spring web application. When the application context has started I use `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` to perform some application initalization, in particular I load data from a web service. If this web service is not reachable then my application cannot do anything useful and it does not make sense to keep it running. Is there a way to programmatically shutdown the application context?

I have tried to do the following:

```
if (contextRefreshedEvent instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext)
{
    ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext
            = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) contextRefreshedEvent;
    configurableApplicationContext.close ();
}
```

However rather then closing gracefully that produces the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

So what is the proper way to shutdown the application in such a situation?

Comment: you could set some scheduled operation to check if service is up, and wait until it is. But closing application by exception at startup is okay. Alternatively you could just catch exception and run system.exit(0) with logging reason if it's listed in some list of exception or streight out exception otherwise

Comment: Calling `System.exit` is a pretty bad idea as if yu are unlucky that also might kill your server, which is hardly what you want. Just throw an exception which basically stops the application from starting.

Comment: I am aware of the option to use `System.exit` but I agree with @M.Deinum that it is not a very good idea. Is there no clean way to do this which avoids throwing an exception?

Comment: If you start calling close you will eventually run into issues, especially if you have multiple contexts (i.e. `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`. ). throwing an exception is basically signaling an exceptional case, which will be handled by the framework and should result in cleanly stopping your application.

Comment: Never said it was good idea, it's an option (hardly good one). Throwing exception is acceptable way.

Comment: The problem is, that the application does not shutdown due to the exception being thrown, the artifact deployment completes and I can access the web site, but because the application did not initialize correctly most of my rest endpoints do not function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an `ApplicationContextException`. It worked for me with Spring 4.2.7.RELEASE